# How can I verify if a file only contains numbers in C?

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in learning C. If I have a file with the given format:

```
12 20 40 60 80
04 10 34 30 20
```

How can I verify with a function that it's integers only.

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to do this. That is why I can't include my main but I am passing a file into my function.

```
bool check(FILE *fp) {
    int numArray[26];
    int i = 0;
    int num;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &num)) {
        if (isdigit(num) == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Not correct format ");
            return false;
        } else 
        {
            numArray[i] = num;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

If I give it the incorrect format such as

```
12x 10 15 13 10
```

Nothing happens. I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your `fscanf` will return 0 if it ever encounters anything that is not a number (or whitespace), which then cause your loop to end.

Comment: Read the file character by character. Test if each character is a digit or whitespace.

Comment: Your function never returns `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fscanf` will return the number of successfully recognized patterns from the format in the input; if it sees something that does not match the next format pattern (such as a letter for a `%d` pattern) it will reject it and return a smaller number.  So in your case, you can just look for `fscanf` returning 0:

```
bool check(FILE *fp) {
    int numArray[26];
    int i = 0;
    int num;
    int matched;
    while ((matched = fscanf(fp, "%d", &num)) != EOF) {
        if (matched == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Not correct format\n");
            return false;
        } else if (i >= 26) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Too many numbers\n");
            return false;
        } else 
        {
            numArray[i] = num;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Nice...........

Comment: Nice, but be careful.  This does depend on the file not containing values that won't fit into an `int`.  Should the file contain such values, undefined behavior would be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
int is_number(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9')
            return 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

maybe this. so you are looking if variable only has numbers?

Comment: Where does the string come from? How does this fit into reading from the file?

Comment: Use `isdigit()` instead of your own comparisons.

Comment: @Barmar `str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9'` is fine vs the usual problem with `if (isdigit(*str) ...` when `*str < 0`.  Using `unsigned char *ustr = str; .... if (isdigit(*ustr) ...` would be best.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `isdigit()` is documented to take `int`, not `unsigned char`.

Comment: Well if you read file its probably in string format?

Comment: @Barmar The `is*()` functions can be subtle.  See [**7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>`**, paragraph 1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4p1): "The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @AndrewHenle If you're reading from a file, how will you get anything else?

Comment: @Barmar A `signed char` with a negative value when passed to a function taking an `int` parameter becomes a bit value that can't be represented as an `unsigned char`.  Thus UB.  Subtle, and nasty.

Comment: And admittedly I've never seen an implementation that failed to handle it as you would expect.

Comment: AndrewHenle The usual hole is -1/255 as the typical `is...()` implements -128 to 255 and so many `is...()` are OK, except `isalpha()` fails with ÿ vs. EOF.  @Barmar calling with negative is UB (Aside form `EOF`).  Using `unsigned char *` also avoids the rare non-2's complement -0 issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok maybe this works better

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    char s[100];
    int i = 0;

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file");
        exit(1);
    }

    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        if(isdigit(c) == 0)
        {
            printf("Not only integers\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    if(c == EOF)
        printf("Only integers\n");

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

but yeah its pretty much same thing